Which electrons interfere in the double slit experiment?
In the double slit experiment, single electrons are fired at the double slit barrier. These electrons interfere with themselves, but do they also interfere with other electrons in the past and future in the same experimental setup?

How would they interfere with electrons in the past or future?

@JonCuster Some recent experiments seem to suggest that some particles passing through a single slit interfere despite despite being separated in time from each other. A particle can be in a superposition of being in two places at the same time, so presumably it can also be in a superposition of being in two different times at the same place.

@KDP this is a complete digression, but I have often wondered about that idea. In physics we seem to assume by default that while objects have a spread in space they exist at an infinitesimally small instant in time. It seems to me that if objects had a corresponding spread in time, that might have detectable effects.

@my2cts It's not my question.

This video with Brian Greene discusses temporal entanglement and entanglement swapping experiments (skip to the 27:27 time mark) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twY2q1F-ciI&t=1654s

@JeffGuarino I think it would help getting your question reopened, if you provide a reference to a paper that describes an experiment where these results were observed.

The old saying by Dirac and Feynman "interfere with themselves" is historical and dated, the modern saying would be "they determine their own direction".   The point of the saying was that these earlier scientists knew that the particles acted independently.
A better understanding of this is that the EM field guides any path taken and that the excited electron in the electrode (even before its emission) is already interacting with the EM field of the apparatus, i.e. the slits and all the other boundaries in the apparatus (all the electrons).  It is the EM field that has the "interference" ... it is affected by the double slit geometry/electrons .... it can be in that state for a long time.
There is no interaction with the past or future in general ... it is possible (with electrons) that if surfaces become charged by prior electrons the EM field would be altered.
The EM field guides all, the electrons and photons in the DSE are dumb.  There are excited electrons prior to photon creation ... all photons come from excited electrons. Excited electrons are strong contributor to the EM field.

My mind is struggling with the following question, so please help me to understand. According to Stochastic Electrodynamics (SED), particles are influenced by a fluctuating electromagnetic background field; they are subject to continuous random perturbations due to this zero-point field. Does the probability for the position of a particle go strictly down to a mathematical zero? In other words: according to SED, is the probability distribution finite or it extends infinitely?

@PavelBorisov I read wiki on SED. It basically says we can add an EMF field (with random zero point energy) to the classical field to explain quantum/QED phenomenon. My main point in the above answer is to state the obvious .... that the EM field is very dynamic and considers all charges and excitations .... thus there is no mystery in the DSE ... but the established norms of physics (based on 1920s QM)  want us to believe otherwise.

@PavelBorisov  The random fluctuations in SED are certainly an important property ... but probably don't have as large a magnitude as an excited electron in an atom.   SED is post QED ... and the physicists like QED ... but SED is perfectly fine as well.  In modern quantum physics there are many competing fine theories .... and some that are also full of baloney .... like FTL.

So, does the probability for the position of a particle go strictly down to a mathematical zero?

The stochastic interpretation interprets the paths in the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics as the sample paths of a stochastic process.[9] It posits that quantum particles are localized on one of these paths, but observers cannot predict with certainty where the particle is localized. The only way to locate the particle is by performing a measurement.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_quantum_mechanics

@PavelBorisov. see above from wiki.   and ... "An observer can only predict probabilities for the outcomes of such a measurement based on their earlier measurements and their knowledge about the forces that are acting on the particle. "

@PavelBorisov all/most precision positional information relies on photons/light/visible, from the EM field and therefore accuracy is limited by wavelength.  The larger the object .... the more the precision relative to the wavelength.  Like Einstein said ... it's all relative.

Thanks for all your answers on that board - i am really fascinated by the ideas that you share here. However, I will try to re-phrase my initial question (it is not related to the electron interference). I want to know your opinion on the following question: in the framework of SED, is there non-zero probability (no matter how fantastically small) for the cup in front of me to move suddenly 1 centimetre away due to the random fluctuation of EM field which is everywhere in the Universe?

I will try to add more details for my question in order to make it clear. According to you, the interaction between matter is guided by the pervasive EM field which is everywhere around us. This EM field is constantly fluctuating and thus it impacts the position of subatomic particles and even individual atoms/molecules. So, is there non-zero probability for the EM field to accidently fluctuate in an extremely rare way, so that a macrscopic object (a cup on the table or a tennis ball on the floor) to move away spontaneously?

@PavelBorisov Some probabilities are just too small to talk about.  In your cup example ... you are actually trying to move protons and neutrons ... too small a chance. It's more likely that an electron will annihilate a proton once in year in one out of a million cups (just my rough guesstimate - no calcs done).  Energy perturbing an electron to make light happens gazillions of times .... the EM field does a lot of work here.
